# Transaction outputs with value 0

Tags: transactions, value, raw-data

If I am correct, some transactions have outputs with "value" field equal to 0, and some even have *all* their output "value" fields equal to 0.

See for instance:
[transaction 9173744691ac25f3cd94f35d4fc0e0a2b9d1ab17b4fe562acc07660552f95518](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9173744691ac25f3cd94f35d4fc0e0a2b9d1ab17b4fe562acc07660552f95518)

I wonder if this is a feature or a bug, and what it means to send 0. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outputs with 0 value are allowed by the protocol. It is a feature that allows for provably unspendable outputs to not have to have any value that then becomes burned. However 0 value outputs are not limited to just provably unspendable outputs, so transactions like the one that you have found are possible. It is also possible to spend those 0 value outputs, but this ends up just wasting money because there is a non-zero fee cost to spending them.